# Minimum amount of water in coffee

Tags: ground-coffee

I have a sunbeam coffee maker. The lowest line for heating water is at 4 cups. However, I rarely drink 4 cups at home. Can I heat, say 2 cups for instance?

Comment: Welcome! Could you please add a few details? Not being familiar with the name, I did a quick google search and found “Sunbeam” is a brand that makes a quite diverse range of coffee maker types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to make only the amount you need - the markings on the glass carafe are only for water measurement - there's no "minimum" water amount! Carefully measure out 2 cups of water (I use a pyrex measuring cup) and add the appropriate amount of grounds (however strong/weak you like your coffee) and you should have 2 fresh cups of coffee within minutes. In the hotter months, I usually make more than I need and put the remainder into a container in the fridge for iced coffee later :)

Answer (score 0):

I think so as the water is usually drown up from the bottom. I don't think that you can harm anything by testing, especially if you keep an eye on it.